# Magento 1.9 store integration with Click & Drop

Tags: magento-1.9

my magento 1.9 store is integrated with royal mail click & drop. i am successfully create Soap/XMLRPC - User and Role with UserName and API key.
i am providing this UserName and API Key to Click & Drop settings.
but when i click the update connection in click & drop settings it will shows "Connection to your marketplace failed. Please check your details and try again".
please any one help me solve this issue. is any log file shows the actual error information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using nginx or apache? You can check the access and error logs there. (On Linux they'll be in /var/log)

Your SOAP URL should be like `http://your-site.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl`